# Alamofire (json, request, delay)

Tags: ios, json, alamofire, swift4

i have a `json request` and my problem is that the `response` from the server does not have time to come and because of this I get an error because I'm working with data (in `viewdidload()`) which is not yet available. I tried to read about synchronous and asynchronous requests but I don't understand how to do them.
in `viewDidLoad()` i call my fucn which is call to the my server and i wait a json, after executing the function, I start working with the data that should come , But the code does not wait for the moment when they come and go further. Can I specify a delay or something like that?

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
        (response: DataResponse) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(let value):

            let json = JSON(value)

            for index in 0 ..< json["items"].count {

                let path = json["items"][index]

                self.Data.append(ProfileModel())

                self.Data[index].name = path["name"].stringValue
                self.Data[index].email = path["email"].stringValue
                self.Data[index].created = path["created"].double!

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            break
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Call your `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`